# Output compiler options from SSH

Tags: ssh, compiling, selinux, configure

How can I list the configuration options that ssh/sshd was compiled with?

I'm attempting to troubleshoot a SELinux configuration issue, and want to make sure that SSH was compiled with `--with-selinux`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to list compilation options, but something like SELinux support should be apparent from the libraries that the executable is linked against:

```
$ ldd /usr/bin/ssh /usr/sbin/sshd | egrep '^/|selinux'
/usr/bin/ssh:
/usr/sbin/sshd:
        libselinux.so.1 => /lib/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007fbbfed5f000)
```

Looks like `sshd` has SELinux support but `ssh` doesn't (why would it?) on my system.

Another thing you could check (e.g. in case you had a static binary) is if there binary references some SELinux functions.

```
strings /usr/sbin/sshd |grep -i selinux
```

Comment: Thanks for the reminder about lld. Since sshd is for incoming connections it thus needs to be able to transition SELinux domains for users logging in. SSH by comparison is for outgoing connections and would not need to interact with a SELinux configuration itself (unless you ssh to yourself, in which case sshd is controlling the SELinux transitions anyway).

Answer (score 1):

I think you may need to look at the packaging system for your distro and find the options it compiles with. Some programs can output their compile flags, but I don't know of such an option for sshd.

Answer (score 1):

If you are installing the default distribution packages, and

- the distribution is Debian based, look at the `debian/rules` file (basically a Makefile) in the package source for the configuration options.
- the distribution is rpm based, look at the compilation options, probably in the source rpm's spec file.

For custom distributions like Gentoo, where there are no default compilations options, this is more difficult, and I'd talk to the person who built the package, and also look at `ldd` as people have suggested.

If you specify your distribution, as you should have done initially, people can presumably give you more specific pointers.